# how to use jquery datepicker in jsf

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to use the jquery datepicker: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

But I don't know what I need, and here is my code:

```
<script src="css/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="css/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="css/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="css/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true
});
```

The place I put my datepick is like:

```
<h:inputText styleClass="datepicker"></h:inputText>
```

But now, when I click on the inputText, the datepicker is not displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you set up datepicker after page is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true})
});
```

Comment: almost there, but the css doesn't get loaded. do you know why?

Comment: have you used jquery datepicker before? do you think i have all the css and js files needed?

Comment: You need css from jqueryUI, have a look at demos page: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ and view source.